# unix screen logging change filename to window name

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, gnu-screen

I know its possible to change the name of the logfile with "set filename"

I'd like to have screen write its log files to the name of the window. how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

check the man and you will find that there is an escape

```
t    window title
```

that can be used in filenames

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed "or filenames". 

"logfile ~/logs/%t.log" does the tricks in .screenrc.

Comment: Feel free to vote up or accept the answer :)